# StopPropagation of keyboard events

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-events

I have this little bit of HTML

```
<input id="legalWellName" readonly data-bind="value: LEGAL_WELL_NAME" class="welllabel" />
```

and this script:

```
$('#legalWellName').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) { e.stopPropagation(); }
    if (e.cancelBubble != null) { e.cancelBubble = true; }
});
$('#legalWellName').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) { e.stopPropagation(); }
    if (e.cancelBubble != null) { e.cancelBubble = true; }
});
$('#legalWellName').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) { e.stopPropagation(); }
    if (e.cancelBubble != null) { e.cancelBubble = true; }
});
```

However, if I click into the legalWellName input and hit BACKSPACE, it acts as if I have hit BACK in the Browser (IE9).  Is there something special about BACKSPACE?  I have already set readonly, so no other keys have any effect (I didn't even need the stopPropagation logic).  How can I prevent the BACKSPACE from taking effect?

Comment: You can try with `e.preventDefault()` and for IE `e.returnValue = false`.

Comment: @Teemu - That worked for me.  if you want to put that in the form of an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I've made the comment as an answer, but I'm just curious, in what kind of situation IE redirects when hitting `Backspace`? It should not, when the `input` has focus. Though I've seen this happening in jsbin.

Comment: In my case, I used an input tag, to be able to use the data-bind="value: XXX" attribute for the display value, and I added the readonly attribute.  Then, when I clicked into the input box, readonly successfully prevented me from changing anything, but Backspace caused a redirect.  I have another page laid out exactly the same way where the Backspace did not do this: the only difference (I could tell) was that, in the one case, the model was a DataTable and XXX was a column name; in the other case (with harmless Backspace), the model was an object and XXX was a property name.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in IE (also in IE10). Adding `readonly` to an `input type="text"` causes IE to navigate back when `Backspace` is pressed on `input`. Even the fact that `document.activeElement` refers to the `input`, doesn't prevent `Backspace`'s default action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prevent bubbling only prevents event to bubble from element to another in the DOM. Looks like you'd rather like to prevent default action of <kbd>Backspace</kbd>:

```
if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
e.returnValue = false;
```

Notice, that you can safely add a property to `e` without feature detection.